# How do I delete my Discussion?

Tags: support, discussions-space

The problem is: I don't have any button to delete my discussion (it has some replies).

So, is it possible to do that? Or is it intended to be that way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can delete Discussions (even with a reply), but it's not exactly intuitive how.

First, click the "Edit" link below the post:
[image: Image of the initial post of a discussion with "Share", "Edit", and "Flag" links]

Then click the "Delete" button in the upper right of the editor UI:
[image: Image of edit UI with buttons labeled "Cancel", "Delete", and "Save edits" in the upper right]

You'll then be prompted to confirm that you indeed want to delete the post:
[image: Confirmation prompt showing "Are you sure you want to delete 'name of post'? This will lock the post and make it visible only to Moderators and the post author."]

Comment: Note: I did not test this with two or more replies, only one.

Comment: yes, it worked with more replies. Thanks!