# Make deleting discussions more intuitive

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, user-interface, discussions-space

In my [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428091/how-do-i-delete-my-discussion) asking "How to delete a discussion?" I got an answer that:

> You can delete Discussions (even with a reply), but it's not exactly intuitive how. [description of how to do that here...]

This solution works fine, but it's extremely unintuitive: on Q&A there is "Delete" link under the post, but not so in Discussions.

That link should be added to the "Discussions" interface too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we add undeletion capability for post authors, the "delete" option will be added to the bottom menu bar (like on questions and answers). Until then, there is the less intuitive route available.

I updated the [Discussions Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/discussions) so that it's clear how an author can delete a post.